# Axon: Using Cassandra as a Event Store

Tags: cassandra, token, axon

We are attempting to implement our own Cassandra-based Event store that extends EmbeddedEventStore. Any thoughts on why this may not work with Axon such that we see the same behavior as if using JPA? One doubt revolves around the fact that Cassandra supports eventual consistency. Currently, we're seeing unexpected behavior when using a multi-threaded TrackingEventProcessor within a single JVM and/or when deploying Saga-based applications in different JVMs with logs as follows:

```
o.a.e.TrackingEventProcessor : message=Unable to claim the token for segment: 0. It is owned by another process
```

It seems as though it always tries to retrieve from segment 0.

This may very well be our own defect (perhaps with our bean configurations **KafkaPublisher/EventProcessorConfigurer**), which we'll resolve, but the bigger question is, in your opinion, is it possible to make Cassandra work with Axon. I recall seeing some posts in the google groups forum stating Cassandra support wasn't considered due to performance issues. We want to ensure we're not investing into something that will be a nightmare to maintain or simply isn't a good solution.

Comment: Some of your wording makes be doubt @blackcompe. Are you looking to create an `TokenStore` of Cassandra or an `EventStore`? It is your use of `EmbeddedTokenStore` which makes me doubt. There is an `EmbeddedEventStore` in Axon Framework, but there is no `EmbeddedTokenStore` at all. Furthermore, the "performance argumentation" on the user group when it comes to Cassandra is about event storage, not token storage.

Comment: Just wanted to reply to your "I recall seeing some posts in the google groups forum". As you probably know the google group moved to [the new discuss platform](https://discuss.axoniq.io/) where all the old posts are imported and searchable. What you may not know is that there you can mention and/or DM people. That may be a good way to get in touch with someone who has played with that combination in the past.

Comment: @Steven: Iol, yes, I meant EventStore.

Comment: @MilenDyankov: I'm aware. I bounce back for forth.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own Event Storage solution whilst using Axon Framework, it is recommended to provide an `EventStorageEngine` implementation.

That way, the `EventStore`, which is of type `EmbeddedEventStore` if you are not using Axon Server, can simply point to the other storage solution for storage and retrieval of events. Samples of `EventStorageEngine` are the `JpaEventStorageEngine`, `JdbcEventStorageEngine` and `MongoEventStorageEngine`. The former two reside in Axon Frameworks event sourcing module, whereas the MongoDb variant is part of Axon's [Mongo Extension](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-mongo).

Now, to your actual question on whether it is doable.
I am very confident you should be able to draft up a `CassandraEventStorageEngine` which does the job just fine.

Whether it is going to be the most optimal Event Store you can have is however very debatable. There is a reason why AxonIQ drafted up Axon Server as an Event Store, and that's simply because all hard requirements you would have for an Event Store are not optimally implemented if you use a different storage approach?
Why? Well simply because things like RDBMS, MongoDb, Cassandra, Kafka, etc provide a broader spectrum of functionality with different intents at its core than an Event Store would.

Providing all the details here would be a bit much, but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=342tqAORbAM) presentation by Allard Buijze (creator of Axon Framework) should give quite some insights into this. Also, why Cassandra wouldn't be the optimal solution to go for.

So concluding, if you strongly feel for building your own Event Store, picking up Cassandra would be an interesting endeavour. If it will bring you *all **you** need* from an Event Store, well that's up for debate.